# Firebase observe call

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-storage

I have a users table and a posts table for a social app. I have the username and profile image in the users database. Now in my tableview postCell file, I am configuring the data to be displayed for each post but for the username and profile image I have to use an observe method on a database reference to the users table for each post. Is this bad/expensive to have the observe call on each cell like this? Or would I be better off attaching username and profile image to each post when I make them? It doesn't seem like these should go here since it is the user data.

This is my call on each post cell:

```
DataService.ds.REF_USERS.child(self.post.userId).child("username").observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) -> Void in

            if let _ = snapshot.value as? NSNull {

                print("User has no username")

            } else {

                self.usernameLbl.text = snapshot.value as? String

            }

        })
```

Comment: Generally speaking, it's best to limit your database calls to as little as possible. You should create a "post" data object, and fill that with the post data so it grabs all the values for the post once rather than twice.

Comment: Stefan, thanks for the reply. I have a post data object with all the info like content, image, likes, etc. But the one thing I need not from the post object is username data which is in the user table in database, so I guess I am asking if it is ok to call observe each cell to get the username string data, or should I put that as part of the post (but user username should really belong to users and not posts)

Comment: Can you provide the JSON tree for your database? Also give the documentation a read. Specifically the section on structuring your data. You're question is likely answered here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/structure-data